# BEAUTIFULSOUP : how to get tag with given string without css selector

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

im currently learning how to scrape webpages.

**THE PROBLEM:**
I cant use css selector, because on other sites the postion (order) of this tag (information about estimated start time) changes.

**MY GOAL:** How can I retrieve the information: *January 2022*

HTML-SNIPPET:

```
<tr>
    <td headers="studyInfoColTitle">  Estimated <span style="display:inline;" class="term" data-term="Study Start Date" title="Show definition">Study Start Date <i class="fa fa-info-circle term" aria-hidden="true" data-term="Study Start Date" style="border-bottom-style:none;"></i></span> : 
    </td>
    <td headers="studyInfoColData" style="padding-left:1em">January 2022</td>
</tr>
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

**1.)** I tried to declare a func to filter out (combined with find_all) this tag:

```
def searchMethod(tag):
        return re.compile("Estimated") and (str(tag.string).find("Estimated") > -1)
#calling here above func
foundTag_s = soup.find_all(searchMethod)
```

this helped me for other similar cases, but here it didnt work, I think it has to do with how the stringtext is devided between the tags...

**2.)** I tried to use the string search:

```
starttime_elem = soup.find("td", string="Estimated")
```

but it doesnt work for some reason.

After many hours of searching I decided to ask here.

**Ref:** https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05169372?draw=2&rank=1

Comment: Instead of scraping, you might be interested in [this](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/resources/download).

Comment: Thx, but I know about it, again Im just trying to learn how to scrape :D I dont even need anything from this side. I finished studying the bs4 documentation and now since yesterday im trying to implement the knowledge :) but cant figure out this problem

Comment: Can you provide an example other site where position changes?

Comment: @QHarr sure, [here for example](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05169359?draw=2&rank=2)

Comment: Think what the question should be BEFORE posting it. Don't go on changing the entire question 2 hours AFTER posting it.

Comment: ? I did not change anything ... or what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are actually looking at different pages within the same domain. The html is basically consistent in terms of elements and attributes.

CSS selector lists are a lot more versatile than just for positional matching. There are numerous ways to solve your current problem.

One is simply to use a css attribute = value css selector to target the start date node then move to the next td

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

links = ['https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05169372?draw=2&rank=1', 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05169359?draw=2&rank=2']

with requests.Session() as s:
    
    for link in links:
        
        r = s.get(link, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        start = soup.select_one('[data-term="Study Start Date"]')

        if start is not None:
            
            print(start.text)
            print(start.find_next('td').text)
```

This is a robust and consistent attribute.

You could also use `:-soup-contains`:

```
start = soup.select_one('.term:-soup-contains("Study Start Date")')
```

Comment: your answer helped me alot, **just a quick** question, I tried it instead of select_one(), with following: `find('span', attrs={"data-term" : "Study Start Date"})`. Can I ask, why you chose select_one() ? Im just curious, thx again!

Comment: Because some DOM parsers are optimized for css selectors giving faster selection.